# cant delete files on an external hd

Tags: external-hdd, delete

I have an external hd, which is not really healthy (several sectors not readable). I guess thats the reason I have some corrupt[image] files

I want to delete these files and found Icant delete any file on this even the properties show that I am entitled to do so.

[image]

any advice? I opened natilus as sudo, no change.

Comment: What filesystem is on it?

Comment: Aaah, noticed $RECYCLE.BIN... Means that it is NTFS. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the device is broken I think your OS mounted the partition read-only. Please check the output of `mount` in a terminal.

I strongly recommend to not delete/write anything on this disk. Instead think about creating a backup of the drive before the disk stops working at all.

Comment: The drive **will** stop working - only a matter of time

Comment: thanks for the advice. According to the readout the drive is mounted with rw.